# ggplot multiple lines with fix scale

Tags: r, plot, scale, ggplot2

I have two set of time series data.
I would like to plot them in a single plot.
Moreover, plot should be in fix scale for y-axis from -3 to 15 and presents a and b where x axis is Time and date and y axis is v1.

Data a :
             TimeAndDate     v1

```
1  2007-09-30 00:00:00 0.3460000
2  2007-09-30 01:00:00 0.1660000
3  2007-09-30 02:00:00 0.2066667
4  2007-09-30 03:00:00 0.2956667
5  2007-09-30 04:00:00 0.2220000
6  2007-09-30 05:00:00 0.6090000
7  2007-09-30 06:00:00 0.8480000
8  2007-09-30 07:00:00 1.1986667
9  2007-09-30 08:00:00 1.4696667
10 2007-09-30 09:00:00 1.6280000
```

Data b:
             TimeAndDate     v1

```
1  2007-09-29 00:00:00 -1.3250000
2  2007-09-29 01:00:00 -0.4670000
3  2007-09-29 02:00:00 -0.4426667
4  2007-09-29 03:00:00 -0.6396667
5  2007-09-29 04:00:00 -0.7843333
6  2007-09-29 05:00:00 -0.5563333
7  2007-09-29 06:00:00 -0.7276667
8  2007-09-29 07:00:00 -0.6260000
9  2007-09-29 08:00:00 -0.7290000
10 2007-09-29 09:00:00  0.4976667
```

Expected results:

[image: plot]

I have merged data as temp by code:

```
 temp <- data.frame(HMn29_29$avg_val,HMn28_29$avg_val,HMn29_29$h)


   HMn29_29.avg_val HMn28_29.avg_val          HMn29_29.h
1        -1.3250000       -1.9225000 2007-09-29 00:00:00
2        -0.4670000       -1.6676667 2007-09-29 01:00:00
3        -0.4426667       -1.5820000 2007-09-29 02:00:00
4        -0.6396667       -1.5716667 2007-09-29 03:00:00
5        -0.7843333       -1.8290000 2007-09-29 04:00:00
6        -0.5563333       -1.6153333 2007-09-29 05:00:00
7        -0.7276667       -1.8093333 2007-09-29 06:00:00
8        -0.6260000       -1.9303333 2007-09-29 07:00:00
9        -0.7290000       -1.3980000 2007-09-29 08:00:00
10        0.4976667        1.2270000 2007-09-29 09:00:00
```

plot code:

```
ggplot(temp, aes( HMn29_29.h)) + 
+     geom_line(aes(y = HMn28_29.avg_val, colour = "var0")) + 
+     geom_line(aes(y = HMn29_29.avg_val, colour = "var1"))
```

How can I fix the y-axes to -3 to 15?

Comment: I'm getting really tired of these graphing questions that read more like a work order than a question.

Comment: @agstudy, I have tried this:  plot(HMn32_30, type = "o", pch = 16, lty = 2, col = "Black", xlab = "Hour  (2007/09/30)" , ylab = "Ambient Tempreture")
 lines(suplmentryfor30, type = "o", pch = 16, lty = 2, col = "Black", xlab = "Hour  (2007/09/30)" , ylab = "Ambient Tempreture")

Comment: @agstudy, there are two problems with my code: 1-scales are different and the plot is not proper 2- I want it in ggplot

Comment: So you haven't made any attempts at all to do this in ggplot.

Comment: you ask for a ggplot2 plot , and you show some code of a base plot codes I will vote to close this question!

Comment: @agstudy I have tried ggplot but there were not any help to multiple data set plotting

Comment: @agstudy, you may help or not help me. Your consideration is appreciated. I only use r limited for my thesis. but it seems you are professional. What you look it like apple pie is a trouble for me.

Comment: @Arun, Yes, Almost something like that.

Comment: @HamedFootohi Try to read your data. plot one time series using ggplot2. Then you need to reshpae the data (melt reshape2 package) to plot multi series datas. When you try this, I and people here will help you.

Comment: The issue here is not that something is easy for us and hard for you. The issue is questions should be based on actual, specific code that you have written (in this case, ggplot2 code). Instead, you simply dumped some data and an expected result on us and said: Here, make this for me. That's just rude.

Comment: @HamedFootohi just edit the question, add any code you have tried out.

Comment: @A.R, My code is in plot command but I need ggplot.

Comment: @Arun, Plz help me and explain the code, I cannot fit my data to the code.

Comment: like @Arun explained, try out. edit the question and add the code you tried (with ggplot2) and we will help you.

Comment: @joran, you can find my answer in question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the tables to a one table:

```
 temp <- data.frame(HMn29_29$avg_val,HMn28_29$avg_val,HMn29_29$h)
```

Plotting:

```
temp <- data.frame(HMn29_29$avg_val,HMn28_29$avg_val,HMn29_29$h)
ggplot(temp, aes( HMn29_29.h)) + ylim(-2,13)+
     geom_line(aes(y = HMn28_29.avg_val, colour = "Temprature")) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = HMn29_29.avg_val, colour = "TempratureA"))+ opts(title = 'chart_title')
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a stab in the dark here for what you want so here you go:

I merged you datasets into a single data frame (df):

```
date time dose data
2007-09-30 00:00:00 0.3460000 A
2007-09-30 01:00:00 0.1660000 A
2007-09-30 02:00:00 0.2066667 A
2007-09-30 03:00:00 0.2956667 A
2007-09-30 04:00:00 0.2220000 A
2007-09-30 05:00:00 0.6090000 A
2007-09-30 06:00:00 0.8480000 A
2007-09-30 07:00:00 1.1986667 A
2007-09-30 08:00:00 1.4696667 A
2007-09-30 09:00:00 1.6280000 A
2007-09-29 00:00:00 -1.3250000 B
2007-09-29 01:00:00 -0.4670000 B
2007-09-29 02:00:00 -0.4426667 B
2007-09-29 03:00:00 -0.6396667 B
2007-09-29 04:00:00 -0.7843333 B
2007-09-29 05:00:00 -0.5563333 B
2007-09-29 06:00:00 -0.7276667 B
2007-09-29 07:00:00 -0.6260000 B
2007-09-29 08:00:00 -0.7290000 B
2007-09-29 09:00:00  0.4976667 B
```

Then plotted it with the following code:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=time, y=dose, group=data, colour=data)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

This yields:
[image]

If you want to change the range on the axes you need to use `xlim()` and `ylim()`